# Typescript compiler throw error: 'error TS2304: Cannot find name' in class

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I want to use external javascript library (MyLib) without typings in my XClient.ts file so I created a dump declaration file for external lib, (myLib.d.ts) When I import myLib to XClient, everything is ok in XClient constructor but typescript compiler throw error at "**readonly _lib: MyLib;**" line of XClient.ts

Compiler error: " error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MyLib'

How can I use external library without typings properly? And why compiler throw error?

```
// XClient.ts

import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as MyLib  from "myLib";

export class XClient {
    readonly _modelId: string;
    readonly _lib: MyLib;

    constructor(modelId: string) {
        this._modelId = modelId;

        this._lib = new MyLib(this._modelId);
    }
}

// myLib.d.ts

declare var inner: any;
declare module "myLib" {
    export = inner;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot find name 'MyLib'

Its there as a *variable* but not as a *type*. More on this : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

## Fix

Probably:

```
declare module "myLib" {
    var inner: any;
    type inner = any;
    export = inner;
}
```

Comment: when I tried above code, compiler throw error. '
message: 'A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.''

Comment: @oguzh4n My bad. Updated answer

Comment: very interesting approach, I am confused :)